# Migrate OpenVPN from Ubuntu 16 to Ubuntu 18

Tags: server, vpn, openvpn, kvm-virtualization

I have a physical machine running OpenVPN on Ubuntu 16. I'm creating a VM to run OpenVPN on Ubuntu 18. Is it possible to migrate the server and client certificates, config, etc. from the physical machine to the VM? I'd like to just be able to change my internal NAT config to point the WAN IP to the VM's LAN IP and not affect the users. I'd like for them to not have to modify their config files (hostname, other options).

**EDIT:**
Non commented lines from config file.

```
/etc/openvpn# egrep -v '^$|^;|^#' server.conf
port 6876
proto tcp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
crl-verify /REV/crl.pem
dh dh4096.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.3.10.3"
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.3.18.7"
push "inactive 36000 10485760"
push "connect-retry 10"
push "connect-retry-max 5"
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret
key-direction 0
cipher AES-128-CBC   # AES
auth SHA256
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status /ramdisk/openvpn-status.log
log-append  /var/log/openvpn.log
verb 4
management localhost 23
explicit-exit-notify 0
```

There is no output of command when specifying the config file; nor is the tun0 int created and the port open.

[image: commands output]

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any reason why this would not work. The configuration files are plain text, and so are the certificates - unless you're using a HSM.

Some configuration options may have changed between OpenVPN-versions shipped in 16.04 and 18.04, but the simplest way to test that is to spin up the VM, copy over configuration, and test the setup.

Comment: Config files are copied over and I've tried enabling and starting the service. It fails. It's not creating the tun0 interface. `journalctl` doesn't give any usable details.

Comment: Edit your question to include the output of what happens when you run `sudo openvpn /path/to/config/server.conf`. This should produce some error messages.